# Pre-Populated realm database with realm file

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have contact.realm file with 10000 records in it. I want to use that preloaded realm file into my app.

Here is my code in app delegate's did finish launching :

```
// Inserting Contacts.Realm file to Default.Realm

let defaultPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL?.path
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ContactDemo", ofType: "realm")

if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: defaultPath!), let bundledPath = path {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: bundledPath, toPath: defaultPath!)
    } catch {
        print("Error copying pre-populated Realm \(error)")
    }
}
```

It works well for the first launch but when I delete the app and relaunch it I am getting 0 counts every time. The problem is that contents of conactDemo.realm is not getting copied into default.realm. Please help me out.

Comment: If it only contained 100 records instead of 10,000 - are you saying that works? If not, then I think you are asking something inaccurate to your issue.

Comment: it's not about the number 100 or 10,000. it's not showing any of the records that are the issue

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code. When the file isn't being copied, are you seeing your error handler called and an error printed? Or does the copy appear to succeed? If it's the latter, my suspicion is that the copy is occurring _after_ your app has already opened the Realm file, which is why you'd continue to see the contents of the file as they were at the point it was originally opened.

Answer (score 0):

Go inside `Realm` class, put breakpoint into `init()` method and just check call trace.

[image]

You should replace this code:

```
let db = try! Realm()
```

by this one:

```
lazy var db = try! Realm()
```

View controllers are instantiated from Storyboard BEFORE `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` should be call before `init()` method of the `Realm` class.